# E764: option 'omnifunc' is not set. Just storing a file in path

Tags: bash, macos, vim, ant, migration

Im trying to set path .bash_profile 
here is what i write: export PATH=&PATH:/usr/local/ant/bin
To exit and save i use Control + X and Control + O but get this error every time: E764: option 'omnifunc' is not set.

Purpose is to install ant migration tool
Im using mac os

Answer (score 1):

You should put :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ant/bin
```

Then
<kbd>Esc</kbd>:wq

<kbd>Control + X</kbd> and <kbd>Control + O</kbd>, is it for `nano` editor ?

Comment: I'm new to this. I'm using it on terminal and i have vim installed. Im using export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ant/bin, it was a type in the question sorry for that. i did this 
sudo vI .bash_profile
-> #export
-> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ant/bin
esc then wq
then CONTROL + X and CONTROL + O
still ant isnt installed

Comment: As @philippe suggested, to save the file and exit, hit the esc key, then type :wq. It seems you missed the colon.